# Running Sonatype Nexus in Tomcat 7.0, Tomcat blocking PUT requests

Tags: tomcat, java, hudson, nexus, maven

I was previously running Nexus 1.8 on OSX and uploading jars for releases without any issues. The OSX box died, so I moved to a FreeBSD server. Since Nexus doesn't have binaries for FreeBSD, I decided to run it in my Tomcat container.

Now, I have set up Nexus 1.9 in Tomcat 7.0 on FreeBSD. Everything is working well, except I can't upload jars to my release or snapshot repositories. If I try via Hudson, I get a 401 error (and no further details). If I try manually via curl, I get an error message back from Tomcat: "This request requires HTTP authentication.".

Why is Tomcat giving this error, and how do I stop it? If I look in the Nexus logs I can see that the PUT request doesn't even reach Nexus, Tomcat is intercepting it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you've enabled the BIO connectior instead of the non blocking NIO connector in Tomcat?